# Using Java agents with IEI (fka LEI)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We have several java agents in our application that will be scheduled to run at different times of the day and wish to use the IEI (IBM Enterprise Integrator, formerly Lotus) product to run them.  We are having issues with them running; although, we are getting messages to print with a system.out.  One of the Notes Admins is saying the agents won't work properly unless we have the required JARs on both the application server and the IEI server.

Can someone confirm this to be the case?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: There are no system.out statements to provide at this time, other than those we created, because we are having a separate issue getting the java agent to open our log database.  However, the question is about whether the JARs are required on both the domino server housing the application and the IEI server being used to run them.  If I can get the Notes Admin to show me something from the server log I'll provide that.

Comment: Obviously your code (which I presume is in Java) cannot run without all the jar files that it requires, but we can't tell if that is your problem. Maybe the jar files are already there and it's another problem. You need to include the diagnostic information from messages that are being printed system.out to your post so we can see them, and then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Responding to your update: Yes. Any jar files used by the agent absolutely must be present on the server where the agent runs. The questions that need to be answered are: what jar files does your agent use? And are they there already on the server in question?

Comment: I should add: it is possible to use Domino Designer to bundle the jar files directly into the agent, so that they will automatically be there on any server that the agent is replicated to or copied to. There are some cases, though, where code in jar files requires permissions that the JVM denies to bundled jars, so sometimes the only solution is to disribute the jars to the servers in the traditional way on the filesystem.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz JARs embedded to Java agent have memory leak issues, it was discussed on internet forums several times. The bigger JAR the sooner server runs out of memory. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO49880

Comment: We understand the JAR files absolutely need to be on the server where the agent runs and they are.  However, what about the JAR files being required on the server where the IEI application resides considering below architecture.

Example:
Application Server:
1) application and agents exist
2) JARs present
3) agents disabled

IEI Server:
1) application doesn't exist
2) no JARs present
3) Scripted Activity to run agent refers to Application Server and agent

Comment: My quesiton is: does the scripted activity retrieve the agent from the application server and run it in the IEI server's JVM? Or does it run the agent on the application server's JVM (similar to a a RunOnServer operation).

Comment: This is the exact question I am trying to get answered myself. I am thinking the agent is ran on the application server's JVM, but the Notes Admin seems to be saying the agent runs in the IEI server's JVM.